# Rundeck Active Directory how to config

Tags: active-directory, rundeck

Can't seem to get Rundeck configured for Active Directory Auth

https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/administration/security/authentication.html

I am in /rundeck/server/config/jaas-loginmodule.conf

What windows command do I run to find these object names?

```
RDpropertyfilelogin {

com.dtolabs.rundeck.jetty.jaas.JettyCachingLdapLoginModule sufficient
      debug="true"
      contextFactory="com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory"
      providerUrl="ldap://hpwidc00011.corporate.local:389"
      bindDn="cn=svc_rundeck,dc=corporate,dc=local"
      bindPassword="X"
      authenticationMethod="simple"
      forceBindingLogin="false"
      userBaseDn="ou=Users,dc=Corporate,dc=corporate,dc=local"

      userRdnAttribute="sAMAccountName"
      userIdAttribute="sAMAccountName"
      userPasswordAttribute="userPassword"
      userObjectClass="user"
      userLastNameAttribute="sn"
      userFirstNameAttribute="givenName"
      userEmailAttribute="mail"

      roleBaseDn="ou=Users,dc=corporate,dc=local"
      roleNameAttribute="cn"
      roleUsernameMemberAttribute="memberUid"
      roleMemberAttribute="member"
      roleObjectClass="group"

      cacheDurationMillis="300000"
      reportStatistics="true"
      timeoutRead="10000"
      timeoutConnect="20000"
      nestedGroups="true";


org.eclipse.jetty.jaas.spi.PropertyFileLoginModule required
debug="true"
file="/securepay/app/rundeck/server/config/realm.properties";
};
```

above and that it works

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Apache Directory Studio](https://directory.apache.org/studio/) To test and obtain the parameters about your AD tree. Take a look at [this](https://standalone-sysadmin.com/connecting-apache-directory-studio-to-active-directory-ac2758d0236e).

To get it work the best way is to create an specific LDAP config file like `jaas-activedirectory.conf` (referenced [here](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/administration/security/authentication.html#active-directory))  and reference it in the windows "start_rundeck.bat" launching script (referenced [here](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/administration/install/windows.html#configuring-rundeck)) in the following way.

```
set CURDIR=%~dp0
call %CURDIR%etc\profile.bat
java %RDECK_CLI_OPTS% %RDECK_SSL_OPTS% -Drundeck.jaaslogin=true -Dloginmodule.conf.name=jaas-activedirectory.conf -Dloginmodule.name=activedirectory -jar rundeck-4.11.0-20230313.war --skipinstall -d  >> %CURDIR%\var\logs\service.log  2>&1
```